# jmonkey rotate and change forward direction?

Tags: jmonkeyengine

How does one rotate a model and change the forward direction of it with the rotation?

I rotate but it just rotates on the axis and the forward is still the same.

This is probably a noob question but it's been kicking me buttocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `look at` method to rotate your spatial to a target point. Below sample makes a spatial look at camera with `up` vector 1,0,0

```
spatial_x.lookAt(cam.getLocation(),new Vector3f(1,0,0));
```

If you just want to rotate about x axis for 0.2 radians:

```
spatial_x.rotate(0.2,0,0);
```

Y axis for 1 radian and Z axis for 3 radians:

```
spatial_x.rotate(0,1,3);
```